# Why can TypeScript not determine that a variable is defined after an if statement that checks for undefined returns never

Tags: typescript, undefined, static-analysis, typechecking

I am compiling in TypeScript 3.6.2 with `strictNullChecks` enabled.

Say I declared a variable that may be undefined:

```js
let filename: string|undefined;
```

Then, a callback *may* assign a value to it, or leave it undefined:

```
doIt(() => filename = "assigned");
```

Now I check whether the callback assigned to `filename; otherwise,`filename`is undefined and I exit the program (return value of`never`):

```js
if (filename === undefined) {
  process.exit(0);
}
```

If this `if` condition is false, that means that `filename` **must** have a valid string value, correct? Finally, I try to use my most-definitely a string:

```js
console.log(filename.toUpperCase());
```

However, I get an error:

```
source/repro.ts:6:13 - error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.

6 console.log(filename.toUpperCase());
              ~~~~~~~~


Found 1 error.
```

As far as I understand, because of the `if` statement above having a `never` return, that means the program terminates before it can reach the following lines that uses `filename`; therefore, `filename` must be a string! Am I missing something here? Why does TypeScript still believe it `filename` could still be undefined after the never return?

---

For reproduction, here is the full program:

```js
let filename: string|undefined;
doIt(() => filename = "assigned");
if (filename === undefined) {
  process.exit(0);
}
console.log(filename.toUpperCase());
function doIt(fn: () => void) {
  fn();
}
```

---

**Note**: I can solve my issue in my real program since I can initialize `filename = ""`, and check for it in the if statement. However, I'm wondering why *this specific approach* will not work.

---

**EDIT**: here's my `tsconfig.json`. I tried this example in a brand new folder WITHOUT a `tsconfig.json` and I could not reproduce this error. Maybe there's something up in my tsconfig, but I haven't pinned it down yet:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es2017",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "declaration": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictBindCallApply": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true
  },
  "include": [
    "source/**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Does `doIt` call its callback **synchronously**? Because if `process.exit` is defined as returning `never`, and `doIt` calls the callback synchronously, that should work, and does here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAUwB4ygCgJQC5FjIBuyATogN4BQitiUAFqXAO4HJsCipzpOA3FQC+VKqEiwEiACZwAklggAjfDkQBeAHyIicGNLw690yjToxgiTAFkAhowB0pW2FkBbNQB5EABgcBWbFM6EMRlATNaERExcGh4JDRbNwAHABtkHHwAZyhSGDAAc2C6DKhEVBy8guKAH0RwaWRgAuRpQUiZeSw1LRLQio1EACJgODhhwRChbA6QiytUDXV1Btdm1oN+0LQMCOnRENJkKBBSJFRBISA

Comment: Basically we need to know more about `doIt`, and are you sure the type information being used for `process.exit` is correct? E.g., does in fact say it returns `never`?

Comment: Actually, even async it should work: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAUwB4ygCgJQC5FjIBuyATogN4BQitiUAFqXAO4HJsCipzpOA3FQC+VKgEMAzgE9IiUJFgJEAEzgBJLHkQAFZgFsYE5AB4icGMoB8lYaPnR4SNGL0AHADbIc+CVFIwwAHMbOkRPKERUHz8A4IAfRHBlZGAA5GVBGjpVDRwAOkZkMEwcRABea2pQ0NRyxAAiYDg4esFQoWxM0JhgRExassHEsGTUwmVsEOraNAwBLNoRBcRSZCgQUiRUQSEgA (although of course the logic would be wrong).

Comment: Can you post your TSConfig information? I just copied it into a TS project that I'm running under 3.6.3 and it inferred the typing properly. If you want to be risky, you can always use the bang operator and declare that the value is definitely not undefined, but that's saying that you're smarter than the Typescript compiler which is not a great thing to just declare. ;)

Also note for syntax reasons, var foo: string|undefined and var foo?: string are the same. Just a little cleaner.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder something odd: i took your example (from my deleted response), and changed `foo` to a function expression instead of a function declaration and now it no longer narrows the type. Could something similar be happening to OP? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/PTAEDMFcDsGMBcCWB7aFnIBQEoBcpoBTAN0ICdQBvAKBFHvvgAszkB3AwjgUTNbJwBuWmAC+I0LFQBneOmSgAvKBz4ipCooB8VCQ1DNWHIjz7IB2YXXFTos+UogwEKNOAyrOG3fsPtOpvxC1OLUUHBIqKAARgCGFviyZIjQAOY+DAA2hHIAHonwyWmgAD6gMAAmhOAphBXC1PqI4CoAsrHMAHRksdAVyAC2OKAAPKAADJ0ArNgZ+vS5jgBE7shLwvqhTS2Yi4r75X3VtRWzNPMMq8Gb1I0MZDmQZGi5wqJAA

Comment: I think it's related to your environment. I modified the code ever so slightly and the playground is able to process your code and infer the type properly: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/DYUwLgBAZglqB2BDAtiAXBAzmATjeA5gD4Cu8AJiLPCOQNwBQ5A9gJJgAUHAlBALwA+aHBBJU-CACJEmTDAI1yk7oxhQIHWAhQh+fPhDKVqtXgG8GECAGNm8TM1AA6YMwIcA5FpAA5HRAB3GUMKKnxaDxUGAF8IEGBMXQsrW3tHEBc3TRExDLBmAFUAByKQHABhGRAeKOiGKDJrMBg7CBZ2TXgMHn4hADdmGHJzS2h4HkZooA

Comment: @NicholasTower - That's fascinating! Happens with an object method, too: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYewdgzgLgBADgJxMAphCMC8MDeAoGQmFADwEsoAKASgC4YwUA3FBXAozqACyQHcGKAQFEESBDQDcHQgF88s6XgBmAVzDAoZcDAAmIAJJVgAI3o0sAPhhMQZXXRt3d7TmWUxKAWQCGPAHQIPmD6ALYWADwwAAz+AKzUrpxEplIyMPLyKuqa2mDEJD6hcAA2KDT00AhkYADmSYRlsCSVUNV1MAA+MOq6KMo1KLpKnPpGlBaY1vjJRCRYMABEyiAgi9KcstQjRO6e85iHPSH9gw4NyYjIaBD+pBRpm3jpCChQqgj5JNKyQA

Comment: @NicholasTower - ...but not with a declared external: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=6&pc=1#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3gBxksIaaAXPAN4BQ818IAHgJYYAUAlKSiAG4gwDcFAL4CKAMwCuKMBgap4wJAEkWYAEak28ALwA+eFyQNg7fYeDkqNBqPjMAslAwALAHQwoKBQFtNAHngADC4ArKwWNBGIqmwCEYJCFGKS0rIotHRQXtgQIGykmDAMKADm4TQ5WHT5GIUl8AA+8JKgokUgwCIRCsrMmrplkfB02vAARKJISKOxNIKsnVY2zMNaq02eIK2cxgORuPiEaC70TDGW1PHn8HAY4jBpdAKCQA I'd think that would be similar to the typing for Node.js `process` but...

Comment: @NicholasTower - Type is [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/node/globals.d.ts). I think this is a reasonable analogue: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=24&pc=2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApQPZIM7eQbwChkTkIAPYMACgQwBMIB+ALmRAFcBbAI2gEo2ICADdoAbkIBfSYwQAbOFBQilyAA6Yc2NuiwRckwjA4gEYYBhDJ6GAJI0EPNtX7IAvAD5kIjMHqCPn70BMSkwDDI1ACycGAAFgB0UHAgtlyuyAA8yAAMiQCsbkSkpchOrpKlUtKExqbmltYUcFzq8hCubNhgUKAA5qGlHWDI5N29A8gAPsimjDCgEPRGpbYO1JleQ2Uk5B7IAEQwGBiHVaRS-KvhkdT77o9zaRCLwgE7u5r6uIkUVJUwiQakDkMowBwoNZyJIpEA Narrows okay. V. odd.

Comment: @Protagonist - That's not an accurate version of the OP's code. `if`/`else` is very different from `if` calling a method that returns `never`.

Comment: I added the tsconfig to my answer. It's definitely something screwy with the tsconfig, because I tried the same code with an empty tsconfig, and it compiles flawlessly 

Comment: EddieAntonioSantos - Titian Cernicova Dragomir tells me that this isn't working for you with v3.6 because v3.6 doesn't handle `never` terminating in that situation yet. v3.7 and above do handle it. The issues that @NicholasTower and I have above relate to limitations around this stuff in various ways. He's doing an answer about it now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the behaviour in Typescript 3.6.3 and earlier, but it actually works the way you want it to in version 3.7.2; here's a [Playground Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAUwB4ygCgnAJsgLkTBAFsAjZAJwEoixkA3axAbwChFEoALKuAO7FkQgKJV+VTDQDc7AL7t2AG2RREwGKrABDUoUQBnKFRhgA5ogA+icPk0Ncc3HACSWaYgC8APg1bkXX1vRAAiHUNDGHNHUNklGGBETE1tPWRvLy9bMHszZFwaNk4UdCwABnjFHDBDOFUAOmU4cxSAoOQGqDgAVQAHPuoAYQjkaXjQSFgERBd3FLAiT19ERjgYQuKuYDBpOUUgA) to see for yourself. If you switch back and forth between versions using the menu, the error appears and disappears.

If this is necessary for your project then you can upgrade Typescript.

---

Basically, the problem was that the control-flow graph is determined before type-checking, so at the time the CFG is formed (and reachability is checked), the fact that `exit` returns `never` isn't available, and hence the CFG branch where `exit` is called continues on to the code following the `if` statement, where the variable is in a possibly-undefined state.

This was [raised as an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12825) in December 2016, and according to [a response in a different thread](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14490#issuecomment-284598510),

> #12825 Generalize handling of never for returns
>
> - The control flow graph is formed during binding, but we don't have type data yet
> - We could store all calls at each flow control point and then check them for never returns and check this info for computing types
>
>   - Expensive!
> - Correct analysis would require multiple iterations

So these are some of the reasons it may not have been solved in versions 3.6.3 and earlier.

Comment: Just as a quick addition to this answer, you can get rid of { "strictNullChecks": true, } to get the error to go away. But that feels like it's not a great idea if you wanted that behavior in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

So the main issue here is that in 3.6 never returning functions did not play into control flow analysis. This feature was implemented in 3.7 by this [PR](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/32695).

I you run your code (with some of the types from the node definitions copied) we can see that it will work in [3.7](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3gBxksIaaAXPAN4BQ818IAHgJYYAUKpKArgLYBGIMASnYgAbvwoBfChQggsAMwayUULiFKYYDFAHN4AH3gcUoRShDAA3BWBIAki2YD4AXgB88RctUIX8AERQRAw65sD+AtYM8vDMXiAqaq4ufsam2hbOlNS4+IRoAHT0TMwADJGSFMjoSLIFEEg6cUoJPgUYSACq2Nj8AMJBIE4V8sZgGAyo8LYOcWyxzu7wIkgMwFlUnihO1hJAA) but not in [3.6](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ts=3.6.3#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3gBxksIaaAXPAN4BQ818IAHgJYYAUKpKArgLYBGIMASnYgAbvwoBfChQggsAMwayUULiFKYYDFAHN4AH3gcUoRShDAA3BWBIAki2YD4AXgB88RctUIX8AERQRAw65sD+AtYM8vDMXiAqaq4ufsam2hbOlNS4+IRoAHT0TMwADJGSFMjoSLIFEEg6cUoJPgUYSACq2Nj8AMJBIE4V8sZgGAyo8LYOcWyxzu7wIkgMwFlUnihO1hJAA)

Also the arrow function that sets the variable really has no bearing on the result. Typescript will not do any control flow analysis on how a callback is called from `doIt`. This is detailed in [this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998)issue.

Just take care with 3.7 and never retuning functions, the conditions for them to participate in control flow are pretty strict:

> A function call is analyzed as an assertion call or never-returning call when
>
> - the call occurs as a top-level expression statement, and
> - the call specifies a single identifier or a dotted sequence of identifiers for the  function name, and
> - each identifier in the function name references an entity with an explicit type, and
> - the function name resolves to a function type with an asserts return type or an explicit never return type annotation.
>
> An entity is considered to have an explicit type when it is declared as a function, method, class or namespace, or as a variable, parameter or property with an explicit type annotation. (This particular rule exists so that control flow analysis of potential assertion calls doesn't circularly trigger further analysis.)

So  function expression might not participate in CFA if it does not have an explicit annotation

```
const exit = () =>  {
  throw new Error()
}

let filename: string | undefined;
if (filename === undefined) {
  exit();
}
console.log(filename.toUpperCase()); // error
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYewdgzgLgBApgDwJawLwwBQEoaoHwwwDeAUIVABYBOIA7jGHPQKJU1XYkC+JJANnFgAzJALABDALZwAXDGhUkYAOYwAPjACuYACZwRjHQG4SSIZhFipcXKnTa9BuDpylCiFNhM9QkEAIA6PhBlDEs4CWkAqBAAVQAHeLgqAGFxCDhsLCMYAHpc+DYQKhggA) 
With an explict annotation it works:

```
const exit: () => never = () =>  {
  throw new Error()
}

let filename: string | undefined;
if (filename === undefined) {
  exit();
}
console.log(filename.toUpperCase()); // error
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=9&ssc=47&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBApgDwJZQFwwBQEoYF4B8MYcAbnAE56Y4EwwDeAUHVABbkgDuRc3AouQ7lsjAL6NGAGziwAZkmlgAhgFs46aOSRgA5jAA+MAK5gAJnHnFTAbkZJZmeYtVw8uXMbMXtcUziZ0iCjYtuKgkCDSAHSSIDoYTnDKalFQIACqAA6ZFADCShBw2FjWMAD0ZfCCIJRAA)